# Need chained select boxes to ALL appear before selecting values for the first select box

Tags: php, jquery, select, chained

My chained select boxes currently work fine.  The first select box is vehicle make or vmake, and the second box is vehicle model or vmodel.  Right now, only the vmake select box appears when the page loads and the vmodel box only appears after you select a value for vmake.  My client wants the vmodel and vmake select boxes to appear when the page loads (even though the vmodel box would be empty until the user makes a selection from vmake).    It sounds silly, but the client really wants it this way.

Here is the jquery code from the main page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wait_1').hide();
    $('#vmake').change(function(){
      $('#wait_1').show();
      $('#result_1').hide();
      $.get("func.php", {
        func: "vmake",
        drop_var: $('#vmake').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_1').fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
});
function finishAjax(id, response) {  $('#wait_1').hide(); $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
$('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
</script>
```

This is the HTML that calls up the php page

```
<select name="vmake" id="vmake">

  <option value="" selected="selected">Make</option>

  <?php getTierOne(); ?>

</select> 

<span id="wait_0">
</span>
<span id="result_1"></span>
```

This is the php script for getTierOne that calls up my database

```
function getTierOne(){$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT vmake FROM vmake") 
or die(mysql_error());

  while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 

    {
       echo '<option value="'.$tier['vmake'].'">'.$tier['vmake'].'</option>';
    }}
```

And lastly this is the rest of the php

```
 if($_GET['func'] == "vmake" && isset($_GET['func']))
 {vmake($_GET['drop_var']); 
}
function vmake($drop_var)
{  
include_once('db.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vmake WHERE vmake='$drop_var'") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="vmodel" id="vmodel" style="width:242">
          <option style="width:242" value=" " selected="selected">Model</option>';

           while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {
              echo '<option style="width:242" value="'.$drop_2['vmodel'].'">'.$drop_2['vmodel'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select> ';}
```

Im not sure what I need to change to get the vmodel box to appear when the page loads.  Thanks for any suggestions, sorry for the long question.

Comment: I think nothing is wrong with your code you just have to call the vmake function since it's going to echo the vmodel from there it's just that the function is going to require the drop_var parameter for it to work. :)

Comment: so what changes would I make to the code to do that?  I am just learning, thanks.

Comment: create a dropdown on the page for your vModel which is visible on thepage. Call AJAX onchange of vModel and get the dropdown options from the response and add options to the vModel dropdown.

Comment: If I use the AJAX idea (which is a great idea) I would have to retool the entire thing.  I just want to know if there is an easy fix anywhere in there, or if I added a vModel that was visible on the page, how I would alter this code to just update that instead of echoing an entirely new vmodel

Comment: call the vmake on the part you want the vmodel to be displayed and include a default vmake on it else just as @Rookieatthis recommends create an entirely new vmodel select element

Answer (score 0):

```
     A dropdown inside another dropdown? Is that posible?

    <select name="vmake" id="vmake">

        <option value="" selected="selected">Make</option>

           <?php getTierOne(); ?> //this function will output   

          "<select name="vmake" id="vmake">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Make</option>
         </select>"

     </select>
```